# Question about ideals of a ring: $IJ=I \implies J=I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Doing exercises, this question came to my mind.

> 1. Is it true that if $I$ and $J$ are proper and nonzero ideals of a ring $R$, $$IJ=I \implies I=J?$$
> 2. And $$IJ=I \iff I\subseteq J?$$

Comment: Counterexample: $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=(2), J=(1)$

Comment: Clearly $I \subset J$.

Comment: Please, change “proper” into “proper and nonzero”, so the question is much more interesting. Otherwise $I=\{0\}$ always gives a counterexample, unless the ring is a field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automatically if $I=IJ$ then $I=IJ\subseteq J$ i.e. $I\subseteq J$. But equality isn't necessarily true.

Consider $R=F\times F\times F$ and the ideals $I$ and $J$ generated by $(1,0,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$.

Moreover, equality can occur when $I=I^2$ but can't occur if $I\ne I^2$.

Comment: The question was naively formulated. The OP should have asked $R$ an integral domain in order to prevent such immediate answers.

Comment: @user26857 I won't claim that being naive is immoral (so to speak), but that is certainly a more interesting question. There do exist idempotent ideals in domains so I can't go around the "true" question the obvious way... I am thinking about it for the moment.